# Can we use android fingerprint scanner to get finger pattern and store that pattern somewhere else?

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-fingerprint-api

I want to use android fingerprint scanner to store fingerprints of my own in my android application not in device OS and later I want to compare them. and use them for other purposes. If there is a way to use android fingerprint scanner like this please let me know. Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android Fingerprint Raw Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34472663/android-fingerprint-raw-data)

Comment: @emandt I don't to access the raw stored fingerprint from device. I want to use device fingerprint to store my fingerprint data or pattern somewhere else. I want to use sensor for like attendance system.

Comment: In posted link it is written that fingerprint memory cannot be accessible outside internal Trused Area. This is a security reason. So the sensor cannot be used outside that Protected/Trusted Area.

Comment: @emandt My English is not very good thanks for explaining to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is NO. Fingerprints are highly confidential and Android does not allow users data or any form of processed or raw fingerprint data to leave the trusted environment (Mobile hardware). for more information you can read about Fingerprint HIDL.